# What kind of Django has caches

Tags: django, caching, django-caching, django-cache-machine

For example, there are caches like hazelcast.

So in django cache types which have ?

Whichever is most preferably ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many type of caches in Django:

Template cache, DB cache, Filesystem cache, cache like Memcached or Redis... I think you have to go deeper on what you want to cache... dont do cache only because you think you need it, do it when you really need it, since it can become tricky.

take a look at this link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/